# quarkus native image failing with "exec ./application: exec format error"

Tags: docker, quarkus, graalvm

facing this issue, getting below error, when i try to follow [https://quarkus.io/guides/building-native-image]

and build native image for quarkus app and run its docker image,

```
exec ./application: exec format error
```

i am using mac M1, with below java and maven versions

ad@ad-MacBook-Pro code-with-quarkus % **mvn --version**
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec
Java version: 18.0.1.1, vendor: Homebrew, runtime: /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/18.0.1.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "11.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

ad@ad-MacBook-Pro code-with-quarkus % **java --version**
openjdk 17.0.3 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 22.1.0 (build 17.0.3+7-jvmci-22.1-b06)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 22.1.0 (build 17.0.3+7-jvmci-22.1-b06, mixed mode, sharing)
ad@ankits-MacBook-Pro code-with-quarkus %

i have performed steps

1. quarkus app was working locally
2. installed grallVM (able to run basic hello world program natively)
3. ./mvnw package -Pnative
4. ./mvnw package -Pnative -Dnative-image.docker-build=true
5. docker build -f src/main/docker/Dockerfile.native -t quarkus/quarkus-project .
   **until now all worked**
6. docker run -i --rm -p 8080:8080 quarkus/quarkus-project
   this is failing with error (exec ./application: exec format error
   )

can somebody point out what i am doing wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your native executable is probably built for Linux / x86_64, or something like that. I wonder why you do both step 3 and step 4 -- step 3 should be enough, and should build a native executable for macOS / AArch64 (assuming you have GraalVM for macOS / AArch64).

Comment: even i felt step 4 is not needed, but i searched on other threads, they suggested it, so i tried. even if i skip sep 4 i am running into same issue.

Comment: I just noticed that `mvn --version` reports `arch: "x86_64"`. This suggests that you have x86_64 JDK, and since `java --version` reports that it's GraalVM, you probably have x86_64 GraalVM. Therefore, the native executable is x86_64. I'm not a mac user, so I don't know if it would be expected for Rosetta to kick in automatically, but I'd recommend getting AArch64 version of GraalVM and trying again (without step 4).

Comment: getting this when i use  AArch64  graalvm -->Error: Darwin native toolchain (x86_64) implies native-image target architecture class jdk.vm.ci.amd64.AMD64 but configured native-image target architecture is class jdk.vm.ci.aarch64.AArch64.

Comment: btw when i 1st installed graalvm i checked arch command on my terminal it gave ad@ankits-MacBook-Pro ~ % arch
arm64
-----------
thats why i went with arm64 installation.

Comment: As I said, I'm not a macOS user, and at this point, I just don't think I can meaningfully help. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error related to building a native image:

[image]

The error was because I had installed an x64 JDK version instead AARCH64 JDK. In my case use Amazon Corretto.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the quarkus-container-image-jib extension and running from an M1 macbook. I had the same issue. When I look at the container image in docker I notice it says it was for AMD64.

After I added `-Dquarkus.jib.platforms=linux/arm64/v8` to the command line argument the AMD64 label disappeared and the container worked:

full command used:
./mvnw clean install -Pnative -DskipTests -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true -Dquarkus.jib.platforms=linux/arm64/v8

For more details about building container images, see https://quarkus.io/guides/container-image#building